# Schema Stitching in Apollo GraphQL doesn't resolve types from other parts

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I'm trying to make my GraphQL schema composable through [schema stitching](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-stitching.html), but I'm struggling with how to resolve properties of types from a different part.

Here's the schema before decomposing:

```
type Referee {
  id: ID!
  stringProp: String!
}

type Referer {
  id: ID!
  pointer: Referee!
}

type Query {
  referers: [Referer]
}
```

The types both have resolvers, in their respective schemas, that expand object `{ id }` into  `{ id, stringProp }` or `{ id, pointer: { id } }`, so that a query

```
query FromSingleSchema {
  referers: {
    id
    pointer {
      id
      stringProp
    }
  }
}
```

resolves as expected; `Query.referers` resolves to a list of `[{id}]` objects, and each of those in turn resolve first into a `Referer` and then fetches the pointed-to `Referee` through type resolvers.

Now, I try to decompose the schema:

```
// schema A
type Referee {
  id: ID!
  stringProp: String!
}

// schema B
type Referer {
  id: ID!
}

type Query {
  referers: [Referer]
}

// schema Extensions
extend type Referer {
  pointer: Referee!
}
```

and compose it again:

```
// both schemaA and schemaB have been created with makeExecutableSchema
import schemaA from './A'
import schemaB from './B'
// schemaExtensions is just a raw GraphQL string
// resolverExtensions is shown below
import { schemaExtensions, resolverExtensions } from './B'

const schema = mergeSchemas({
  schemas: [schemaA, schemaB, schemaExtensions],
  resolvers: Object.assign({}, resolverExtensions)
})

// resolverExtensions defined as follows:
{
  Referer: {
    pointer: {
      fragment: 'fragment IdFragment on Referee { id }',
      resolve: o => ({ id: o.pointerId })
    }
  }
}
```

With this, I can run this query without problems:

```
query OnlyIdFromDecomposedSchemas {
  referers: {
    id
    pointer {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

but this fails

```
query FullRefereeFromDecomposedSchemas {
  referers: {
    id
    pointer {
      id
      stringProp
    }
  }
}
```

with the error message

> Cannot return null for non-nullable field Referee.stringProp.

What do I need to do for the type resolver for `Referee` to be able to fill in the rest of the properties once `{ id }` is available, like it does in a single, non-decomposed, schema?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [schema delegation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-delegation.html). Schema Delegation is a way to automatically forward a query (or a part of a query) from a parent schema to another schema (called a subschema) that is able to execute the query.

You can use `delegateToSchema` method like this in your resolver:

```
{
    Referer: {
      pointer : {
        resolve(parent, args, context, info) {
          return info.mergeInfo.delegateToSchema({
            schema: schemaA,
            operation: 'query',
            fieldName: 'referee', // modify according to your query for referee
            context,
            info,
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I read about that, but that seems to require me to delegate to a `query` operation on the other schema - I currently don't have one, and I'd like to avoid having to create one just because of this need. Can I delegate to the other schema without having an explicit query operation there?

Comment: I believe the issue here is in fact how your current resolverExtension implements the `resolve` arrow function. Schema delegation actually is neccessary here – I'd be wondering how your existing resolvers already knew how to return the requested field `pointer` and its sub-fields. In your arrow function you are confusing `Referer` (the parent, gets passed to your arrow function) with `Referee`. Use another argument name there, instead of `o` it should be `referer`. And then you either use `delegateToSchema` or you have a simple backend that you can call in place to ask for `pointer`/`Referee`.